# Can I 'order by' date that is in a text field?

Tags: php

Had some coding done by a freelancer and he added the completion date into postmeta > meta_value which is a text field.

Don't fully understand WordPress functions and structure, so thought it best to ask here.

I want to order the list via date.

Can I use `strtodate()` in the WordPress arguments and if so how to I write it for WordPress ?

```
<?php
$args2 = array(
    'post_type'   => 'joblist',
    'post_status' => 'publish',
    'showposts'   => -1,
    'order'       => 'ASC',
);

$slider_loop2 = new WP_Query( $args2 );
```

Comment: what format is the date? And is the entire value of the text field the date or just a portion of the text field? Does the text field have the same meta key or does the name of the meta key change? Where does the field come from?

Comment: Thanks,Date format is Y m d and is stored on its own, yes meta_key name stays the same

Comment: tied to wp_posts via post_id

Answer (score 0):

Your Problem isn't that big. As your meta data is stored in the Y m D format, you should be able to just sort by it (I am going to assume that the format uses leading zeros).

You just add "meta_key" to your query arguments like this:

```
$args2 = array(
  'post_type' => 'joblist', 
  'post_status' => 'publish', 
  'showposts' => -1, 
  'order' => 'ASC',
  'meta_key' => 'completion_date', //change for the correct meta key
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
);
$slider_loop2 = new WP_Query($args2);
```

Be aware: because Wordpress uses an INNER JOIN to join the two tables, with this query there will be NO Posts, that do NOT possess this meta value. So if there are Posts that don't have that value set, they will not be in your query.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Thanks, but that isn't ordering by date, am guessing because it has hyphens which there means you can not order as a number

Comment: So how exactly is the Format? YYYY-MM-DD ? this should work. Maybe you have to swap "meta_value_num" with "meta_value", but the sorting should work correctly...